# Adding image while using function in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter, error-handling

I am new to python GUI and I am getting error while running this block of code,I am searching for how to insert image in tkinter while using functions

```
def do(self):
  self.img = PhotoImage(file=r"file/ball1.png") 
  self.canvas = Canvas(root, width =500, height = 500)      
  self.canvas.pack()      
     
  self.canvas.create_image(50,50, anchor=NW, image=self.img)  
  self.canvas.image = self.img
```

I got this error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SONY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\SONY\Desktop\SPEECH\speech - Copy.py", line 46, in <lambda>
    but1=Button(root,text="START",font=("potra",45),image=photoimage,fg="white",bg="white",compound="center",activeforeground="#13D678",command=lambda:do(1))
  File "C:\Users\SONY\Desktop\SPEECH\speech - Copy.py", line 11, in do
    self.img = PhotoImage(file=r"file/ball1.png")
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'img'
```

Comment: Your function has no name and your indentation isn't ok either.

Comment: OK sorry but I was in hurry so I write wrong code here but I now I have edited the question so see for the solution now

Comment: no this doesn't work at all

Comment: Please post a minimal example.

Comment: You called `do(1)`, so `self` of `do()` will be passed integer 1.  And so the line `self.img = PhotoImage(...)` will be the same as `1.img = PhotoImage(...)` which causes the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function has no name and your indentation isn't ok either. –